# bash script - unable to evaluate variable to string correctly

Tags: bash, unix

Trying to debug my bash script. What's wrong with my syntax here? I'm trying to evaluate a parameter entered by the user and based on that run one of my `IF-THEN` statements. However, I'm getting a command not found.

Here's my script thus far:

```
if [[ $# != 4 ]]; then
   echo "Usage: ./test.sh <ABC|XYZ> <owner> <db> <TARGETHOST>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

case $1 in
    ABC|XYZ)
       filename="get-$1.sql"
       ;;
    *)echo "Must enter ABC or XYZ"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

export OWNER=$2
export DB=$3
export HOST_NM=$4
export PORT=5432
export LOG="test-$1.log"
PSQL=`which psql`


if [[$1=="ABC"]]; then
      RUNCLI=$("$PSQL" -h $HOST_NM -p $PORT -U $OWNER $DB -F $'\t' --no-align -f get-$1.sql | tee >> $LOG)
      exit 1
   else
      echo "Error running report ..."
fi

if [[$1=="XYZ"]]; then
      RUNCLI2=$("$PSQL" -h $HOST_NM -p $PORT -U $OWNER $DB -a -f get-$1.sql | tee >> $LOG)
      exit 1
   else
      echo "Error running report ..."
fi
```

Error:

```
./test.sh: line 41: [[XYZ==ABC]]: command not found
Error running report ...
./test.sh: line 51: [[XYZ==XYZ]]: command not found
Error running report ...
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: There should be a space after `[[`, before `]]` and probably around the operator.

Comment: If your intent is to write your error message to `stderr`, then `2>&1` should be `1>&2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is already answered in the comment section I want to give an answer and share some knowledge which is not obvious (at least it was not for me).

The `if` in bash just checks the return code of the following command, which means that instead of `if [ condition ]...` or `if [[ condition ]]...` you could also write `if ./configure && make...`.
`[` and `[[` are commands or shell-built-ins, respectively, as well and not part of the if syntax. An `which [` for instance returns `/bin/[`.
At this point it is obvious that you need spaces between the brackets and the condition since it is just just a set of parameters passed to a command.

If you have this in mind, you will never forget the spaces again.